# Regex: Remove lines containing "help", etc

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a long document of commands. Using Notepad++ or regex, I want to delete all lines containing "help" including keyboard_help, etc.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1197, accepted):

This is also possible with Notepad++:

- Go to the search menu, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, and open the *Mark* tab.
- Check *Bookmark line* (if there is no *Mark* tab update to the current version).
- Enter your search term and click *Mark All*

  - All lines containing the search term are bookmarked.
- Now go to the menu *Search* → *Bookmark* → *Remove Bookmarked lines*
- Done.

Comment: Yeah! It also has 'Remove Unmarked Lines', which is like grep, exactly what I needed!

Comment: How to delete/copy lets say 3 consecutive following lines after a bookmarked line for all bookmarks?

Comment: This approach works, but if the file is big (100MB) and many items are bookmarked it becomes very slow to mark them and especially "copy bookmarked items". Grep is much faster(better:)

Comment: checking `BOOKMARK LINE` is important here otherwise it won't work!.

Comment: This works but is a long winded process if you have to repeatedly remove multiple different matches

Comment: It is not work for me, bookmarked line do not deleting

Comment: Instead of ```Ctrl + F``` and clicking "Mark" tab, you can directly press ```Ctrl + M```

Comment: "Remove Bookmarked Lines" did not work for me either, until I realized that I actually did not bookmark lines by clicking "Mark all". The "Boomark Line" checkbox needs to be checked as well.

Comment: @bytedev You can add multiple different search words separated by `|`. Example search words `red|green|blue`. But to get this syntax work, you have to choose "Regular Expression" as Search mode

Answer (score 243):

Another way to do this in Notepad++ is all in the Find/Replace dialog and with regex:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> to bring up the find replace dialog.
- In the `Find what:` text box include your regex: `.*help.*\r?\n` (where the `\r` is optional in case the file doesn't have Windows line endings).
- Leave the `Replace with:` text box empty.
- Make sure the Regular expression radio button in the Search Mode area is selected. Then click `Replace All` and voila! All lines containing your search term `help` have been removed.

[image: How-To Line Replace in N++]

Comment: better answer than using mark tab, since this can be done for "Find in Files"

Comment: Make sure to escape special characters like parentheses with a backslash.

Comment: make sure to uncheck the ". matches newline"

Comment: Better answer due to a higher performance. With files of >1millions lines the bookmark method is stretched to its maximum, also on modern machines.

Comment: This causes the next line to sometimes get indented by TAB. Why?

Comment: @schantischul I'm not 100% sure, but the only thing I can think of is that the regex might be greedy and somehow consuming multiple lines? Maybe try `.*?` instead of just `.*` for a non-greedy match.

Answer (score 22):

Search with a regular expression:

```
^.*(help).*$
```

Comment: What about the deletion part?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Find `\n\n`, replace with `` (nothing)

Comment: In Windows, however, one can do `\r\n\r\n` and replace it with nothing.

Answer (score 19):

Easy task with `grep`:

```
grep -v help filename
```

Append `> newFileName` to redirect output to a new file.

---

#### Update

To clarify it, the normal behavior will be printing the lines on screen. To pipe it to a file, the `>` can be used. Thus, in this command:

```
grep -v help filename > newFileName
```

1. `grep` calls the `grep` program, obviously
2. `-v` is a flag to inverse the output. By defaulf, `grep` prints the lines that match the  given pattern. With this flag, it will print the lines that *don't* match the pattern.
3. `help` is the pattern to match
4. `filename` is the name of the input file
5. `>` redirects the output to the following item
6. `newFileName` the new file where output will be saved.

As you may noticed, you will not be deleting things in your file. `grep` will read it and another file will be saved, modified accordingly.

Comment: @Kevin Duke: Alas! That probably means you don't have `grep` installed. Anyway I'd recommend you installing GNU grep, it will certainly work on Windows, and it's a really useful tool.

Comment: @sidyll it knew what grep was and it did a bunch of output, it could have been because I didn't specify an output file

Comment: @Kevin Duke: as I said earlier in the answer, the output can be redirected. The standard behavior is print on the screen. To redirect, you use a pipe (`>` in this case), giving a final command of `grep -v help filename > outputFileName`

Comment: grep > sed any day of the week for FINDING sequences of characters

Answer (score 14):

You can do this using sed: `sed '/help/ d' < inputFile > outputFile`

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw: At the command line on Linux/Mac/Whatever. If you're on Windows, you'd have to install something like CygWin and use that.

Comment: Thanks @TikhonJelvis ! And one final question, can we do sed 'help/' to delete all the lines **starting** (not containing) with help?

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw: I think `sed '/^help/ d'` should work. The `^` represents the start of the line.

Comment: @jeff PowerShell has `sed` and `grep`

Comment: cygwin may not work on windows with utf-16 files. Cygwin utilities use UFT-8 by default. Very few of them support UTF-16. Use babun http://babun.github.io/. It acts as a wrapper around cygwin, but provides lots of stuff out of the box.

Answer (score 11):

If you're **on Windows**, try `findstr`. Third-party tools are not needed:

```
findstr /V /L "searchstring" inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

It supports regex's too! Just read the tool's help `findstr /?`

P.S. If you want to work with big, *huge* files (like 400 MB log files) a text editor is not very memory-efficient, so, as someone already pointed out, command-line tools are the way to go. But there's no grep on Windows, so...

I just ran this on a 1 GB log file, and it literally took 3 seconds.

Comment: "If you're on Windows," wait, what? I thought Notepad++ was only for Windows?

Comment: @FaranAiki maybe, I don't keep track what OS Notepad++ is for.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it in two steps.

**1. Bookmark the lines having that pattern**

Press *CTRL + M* button. In the find what text box, enter the pattern. Then select the check box labeled as *Bookmark Line*. Then click the button named "*Mark All*". Close the dialog box.

**2. Delete those bookmarked lines**

Press ALT + S(earch) + B(ookmark) + R. Press Enter.

You are done.