# How to remove lines containing similar duplicates?

Tags: php, notepad++

I have a text file which contains URLs. How can I remove duplicated addresses with www, and non www?
For example I have two URLs:

```
example.com
www.example.com
```

I would like to remove one, or remove 'example.com' from www.example.com then I could remove all www.'s

File contains about 8k urls so I can't do this manually

Urls are separated with new lines, or do it in PHP somehow, explode each to array then compare? (this will be a lot time consuming)

Comment: If you know PHP you should forget about notepad++ and do it in PHP. It must be easier.

Comment: I think a PHP regex could do the thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex: Remove lines containing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876296/regex-remove-lines-containing)

Answer (score 1):

In Notepad++ search for "www." then *replace all* with a blank space.
Then make a PHP file and explode them into an array, then use [array_unique()](https://www.php.net/function.array-unique)

Answer (score 0):

I've removed first all www. -> replaced all www. to ''
then removed duplicated:
[Regex: Remove lines containing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876296/regex-remove-lines-containing)