# NP++: Clear complete line

Tags: regex, notepad++

How to clear a complete line in NP++ using the search and reaplace menu? E.g. I search for the patters

> %4

and then want not only to clear this pattern, but the complete line, where it stands in, where a "line" should be, what notepad shows with a line-number on the left.

Is that possible?

Comment: Whats `^.*%4.*$` doing for you when you replace it with an empty string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex: Remove lines containing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876296/regex-remove-lines-containing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^.*%4.*$\n
```

and replace that pattern with an empty string (assuming that your linebreaks are `\n`... If not you can replace it with `^.*%4.*$(\n\r|\r\n|[\r\n])`)