# How to remove a line in notepad++ that has a specific character in it?

Tags: notepad++

Is it possible to remove every line in a notepad++ document that has a specific character in it? For example, in my document I have something like:

```
test1@gmail.com:cool
cool:cool
test2@yahoo.com:cool
```

I want to get rid of all lines that have the character "@" in them, so after it would look just like this:

```
cool:cool
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is.

[Regex: Remove lines containing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876296/regex-remove-lines-containing)

- Search > Find > Mark
- In the "Find what" textfield, enter "@"
- Check the "Bookmark line" and "Wrap around" checkboxes
- Mark All
- Now select Search > Bookmark > Remove Bookmarked Lines"

Answer (score 2):

In find and replace, regex mode:

Find: `^.*@.*$(\r\n)?`
Replace with:

[image]

Output:

```
cool:cool
```