# Notepad++ Remove Lines without Password

Tags: notepad++

> xiangpinglee@hotmail.com:1230asdf
>
> Saharnaya_N_@mail.ru:
>
> duga@rambler.ru:7354205duga
>
> iregina_1983@mail.ru:

remove

> iregina_1983@mail.ru:
>
> Saharnaya_N_@mail.ru:

how to remove lines without password by regex way?

Answer (score 0):

Do a regular expression find/replace like this:

- Open Replace Dialog
- **Find What:** `^.*:(\R|\z)`
- **Replace With:** `` the empty string
- Check **regular expression**
- Click Replace or Replace All

The Regular Expression matches

- everything (`.*`)
- from start of line (`^`)
- to either line end or buffer end (`\R|\z`)
- a match is a line that ends with `:`
- such a matching line is completely (including the lineend) replaced with empty string

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5899441/6419007) with this regex :

```
:$
```

Which means "a colon at the end of the line".

This will remove every line without password.