# How to import missing values in postgresql table

Tags: postgresql, csv

My Csv file has missing entries denoted as -

```
1.2E+09 8.59E+09    In  3   480 5697277130  822277190   OK  1   0   1.23E+09    34295
4.89E+09    9.59E+09    Out 3   480 1677272449  6747272509  OK  1   -100    8.87E+09    21
2.33E+09    4.49E+09    In  4   640 4347277310  4567277370  OK  1   -   3.23E+09    123
 2.33E+09   4.49E+09        4   640 4347277310  4567277370  OK  1   -   3.23E+09
```

I have defined my table schema as follows

```
create table zip_codes(
  Source numeric,
  manual numeric,
  TTYPE varchar, 
  feature1 numeric, 
  feature2 numeric, 
  LBP1 numeric, 
  RLBP numeric, 
  STATUS varchar, 
  NUMBER_OF_TRASVERSE numeric, 
  rank numeric, 
  image_number numeric, 
  parent_class numeric);
```

and my import script from csv file is

```
test_db=# COPY zip_codes FROM 'C:/tmp/dd_1.csv' delimiter ',' csv;
```

my error:

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "-"
>
> CONTEXT:  COPY zip_codes, line 7, column rank: "-"

Should I change the numeric schema of rank to something else to get the - values  imported? Any suggestions on how i can get these values imported.

It is a large csv so is there a way i can import all (-) values?
Any suggestions?

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: You can easily [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876296/regex-remove-lines-containing) specific lines using notepad++

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the string used to denote the Null value. By default, it is \N but you can use any string, as per the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html), using the option `NULL 'null_string'`. It would be similar to

```
test_db=# COPY zip_codes FROM 'C:/tmp/dd_1.csv' delimiter ',' NULL '-' csv;
```

Should you have valid negative values, you may have to play with the string (with tab, comma or else), or to completly change the way you denote the nulls.

Comment: thanks for this ! but if  i have say multiple missing entries . say one is denoted as " " and other is denoted by  "invalid" .is there a way i can combine multiple missing entries?                                                                                                              test_db=# COPY zip_codes FROM 'C:/tmp/dd_1.csv' delimiter ',' NULL '-' ,NULL ' ', NULL 'Invalid' csv; Will this be correct?

Comment: @samvenu I doubt.. You can edit the file to standardize the Null value.