# Find multiple lines in TXT/xml file and remove if criteria met

Tags: xml, vba, notepad++, xmldom

Been wondering if it would be possible to make a simple script to check if multiple criteria are met and make necessary amendments to file.

Moving on to example of what I have and what I want to achieve.

I have an xml file with 4 lines - number, year, model and man.

If `<man>` is Ford or Dodge, I want no amendments to be made. But if `<man>` is anything other than that, then I want to check if `<year>` or `<model>` are "NA" and remove the line with "NA".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CarStuff>
    <fileName>CarExpor201217.xml</fileName>
    <numberCars>5</numberCars>
    <ref>2017XY</ref>
    <carExo id="CAR0001_01">
        <dealVen id="CAR0001_02">
            <name>John</name>
            <surname>Smith</surname>
        </dealVen>
        <soldCar id="CAR0001_03">
            <amount>1811.10</amount>
            <lotNumber>1</lotNumber>
            <year>NA</year>             - Line must be removed
            <model>NA</model>           - Line must be removed
            <man>Acura</man>
        </soldCar>
    </carExo>
    <carExo id="CAR0002_01">
        <dealVen id="CAR0002_02">
            <name>John</name>
            <surname>Smith</surname>
        </dealVen>
        <soldCar id="CAR0002_03">
            <amount>1811.10</amount>
            <lotNumber>1</lotNumber>
            <year>NA</year>         - Line must be kept
            <model>NA</model>       - Line must be kept
            <man>Ford</man>
        </soldCar>
    </carExo>
    <carExo id="CAR0003_01">
        <dealVen id="CAR0003_02">
            <name>John</name>
            <surname>Smith</surname>
        </dealVen>
        <soldCar id="CAR0003_03">
            <amount>1811.10</amount>
            <lotNumber>1</lotNumber>
            <year>1997</year>       - Line must be kept
            <model>NA</model>       - Line must be removed
            <man>Bugati</man>
        </soldCar>
    </carExo>
    <carExo id="CAR0004_01">
        <dealVen id="CAR0004_02">
            <name>John</name>
            <surname>Smith</surname>
        </dealVen>
        <soldCar id="CAR0004_03">
            <amount>1811.10</amount>
            <lotNumber>1</lotNumber>
            <year>1997</year>       - Line must be kept
            <model>NA</model>       - Line must be kept
            <man>Dodge</man>
        </soldCar>
    </carExo>
    <carExo id="CAR0005_01">
        <dealVen id="CAR0005_02">
            <name>John</name>
            <surname>Smith</surname>
        </dealVen>
        <soldCar id="CAR0005_03">
            <amount>1811.10</amount>
            <lotNumber>2</lotNumber>
            <year>NA</year>         - Line must be kept
            <model>Charger</model>  - Line must be kept
            <man>Dodge</man>
        </soldCar>
    </carExo>
    <carExo id="CAR0005_01">
        <dealVen id="CAR0005_02">
            <name>John</name>
            <surname>Smith</surname>
        </dealVen>
        <soldCar id="CAR0005_03">
            <amount>1811.10</amount>
            <lotNumber>3</lotNumber>
            <year>NA</year>         - Line must be removed
            <model>Dot</model>      - Line must be kept
            <man>Datsun</man>
        </soldCar>
    </carExo>
</CarStuff>
```

Grateful for all the comments and ideas.

Comment: Edited/corrected wrong closing tag `</carStuf>` to `</carStuff>` to receive a well formed XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution via XMLDom**

You can use XMLDom and XPath to search in a so called NodeList for `<man>` tags not containing Dodge or Ford strings and check all siblings if they contain "NA" in order to delete them. The code below uses *late binding*. BTW, your xml in OP wasn't well formed (closing tag `</carStuf>` instead of `</carStuff>` - I added a little parse error routine to check this when loading.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub checkNA()
Dim xDoc        As Object    ' xml document
Dim noli, noli2 As Object    ' node list
Dim no, no2     As Object    ' node
Dim noMan       As Object    ' node <man> to check if no Dodge or Ford
Dim s           As String
Dim sFile       As String    ' xml file name

  sFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\xml\na_test.xml"  ' <<< change to your xml file name

' late binding xml
  Set xDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
  xDoc.async = False: xDoc.validateOnParse = False
  xDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
' load xml
  If xDoc.Load(sFile) Then
    Debug.Print "Loaded successfully"
  Else
    Dim xPE        As Object    ' Set xPE = CreateObject("MSXML2.IXMLDOMParseError")
    Dim strErrText As String
    Set xPE = xDoc.parseError
    With xPE
    strErrText = "Load error " & .ErrorCode & " xml file " & vbCrLf & _
                 Replace(.URL, "file:///", "") & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                 xPE.reason & _
                 "Source Text: " & .srcText & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                 "Line No.:    " & .Line & vbCrLf & _
                 "Line Pos.: " & .linepos & vbCrLf & _
                "File Pos.:  " & .filepos & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    End With
    MsgBox strErrText, vbExclamation
    Set xPE = Nothing
    Exit Sub
  End If

' check items
  s = "carExo/soldCar"
  Set noli = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(s)
  For Each no In noli
      Set noMan = no.SelectSingleNode("man")
      If Not noMan Is Nothing Then
         If InStr("Ford.Dodge" & ".", noMan.Text & ".") = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "delete", noMan.Text
            ' delete all subtags containing "NA" as text
            Set noli2 = no.SelectNodes("*")
            For Each no2 In noli2
                If no2.Text = "NA" Then
                   ' delete item
                     Debug.Print , no2.nodename & "=" & no2.Text
                     no2.ParentNode.RemoveChild no2
                End If
            Next no2

         Else
            ' Debug.Print "keep", noman.Text
         End If
      End If
  Next no

' save
  ' Debug.Print xDoc.XML
  xDoc.Save sFile      
' close
  Set xDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Edit 12/29 - Addendum**

I added a second workable version of the `' check items` part using some extra XPath. This alternative simply avoids two `If` conditions in normal code as it narrows the range of found nodes in the two node lists.

```
' check items
  s = "carExo/soldCar[man!='Ford'][man!='Dodge']"   ' << (1) added condition to XPath
  Set noli = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(s)
  For Each no In noli
      Set noMan = no.SelectSingleNode("man")
      If Not noMan Is Nothing Then
         Debug.Print "delete", noMan.Text
       ' delete all subtags containing "NA" as text
         Set noli2 = no.SelectNodes("*[.='NA']")    ' << (2)added condition to XPath
         For Each no2 In noli2
           ' delete item
             Debug.Print , no2.nodename & "=" & no2.Text
             no2.ParentNode.RemoveChild no2
         Next no2
      End If
  Next no
```

**Hint**

Of course there are many streets leading to Rome, see @Parfait 's XSLT approach below.

Comment: Great! Simple and easy to understand.

I'll just need to amend it slightly, just to find <soldCar> node no matter the parent node.

Comment: In case anyone would need it, maybe there's a simpler way, but did it like so:

Set noli = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("descendant::soldCar")

Comment: Glad I could be helpful. I edited my answer with a 2nd workable version permitting to avoid two `If` conditions by including them into the XPath string.

Comment: You can search nodes at any level via a double slash prefix `//`, too. BTW, it isn't necessary in this case to use `DocumentElement` designing the root node, precisely because **all** XML levels are included.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language designed to do exactly what you need in transforming original XML file by removing nodes according to various criteria.

Specifically below runs the [Identity Transform](http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity) to copy XML as is and then excludes the nodes by your criteria for model / year / man.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="soldCar[man != 'Ford' and man != 'Dodge']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="amount|lotNumber"/>
        <xsl:if test="model != 'NA'">
            <xsl:copy-of select="model"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="year != 'NA'">
            <xsl:copy-of select="year"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:copy-of select="man"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**VBA**

```vb
Public Sub RunXSLT()
    Dim strFile As String, strPath As String
    ' REFERENCE MS XML, v6.0
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60 
    Dim newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    ' LOAD XML SOURCE
    xmlDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\Input.xml"

    ' LOAD XSL SOURCE
    xslDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\XSLT\Script.xsl"

   ' TRANSFORM SOURCE
   xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
   newDoc.Save "C:\Path\To\Output.xml"

   ' RELEASE DOM OBJECTS
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing: Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set newDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CarStuff>
  <fileName>CarExpor201217.xml</fileName>
  <numberCars>5</numberCars>
  <ref>2017XY</ref>
  <carExo id="CAR0001_01">
    <dealVen id="CAR0001_02">
      <name>John</name>
      <surname>Smith</surname>
    </dealVen>
    <soldCar>
      <amount>1811.10</amount>
      <lotNumber>1</lotNumber>
      <man>Acura</man>
    </soldCar>
  </carExo>
  <carExo id="CAR0002_01">
    <dealVen id="CAR0002_02">
      <name>John</name>
      <surname>Smith</surname>
    </dealVen>
    <soldCar id="CAR0002_03">
      <amount>1811.10</amount>
      <lotNumber>1</lotNumber>
      <year>NA</year>
      <model>NA</model>
      <man>Ford</man>
    </soldCar>
  </carExo>
  <carExo id="CAR0003_01">
    <dealVen id="CAR0003_02">
      <name>John</name>
      <surname>Smith</surname>
    </dealVen>
    <soldCar>
      <amount>1811.10</amount>
      <lotNumber>1</lotNumber>
      <year>1997</year>
      <man>Bugati</man>
    </soldCar>
  </carExo>
  <carExo id="CAR0004_01">
    <dealVen id="CAR0004_02">
      <name>John</name>
      <surname>Smith</surname>
    </dealVen>
    <soldCar id="CAR0004_03">
      <amount>1811.10</amount>
      <lotNumber>1</lotNumber>
      <year>1997</year>
      <model>NA</model>
      <man>Dodge</man>
    </soldCar>
  </carExo>
  <carExo id="CAR0005_01">
    <dealVen id="CAR0005_02">
      <name>John</name>
      <surname>Smith</surname>
    </dealVen>
    <soldCar id="CAR0005_03">
      <amount>1811.10</amount>
      <lotNumber>2</lotNumber>
      <year>NA</year>
      <model>Charger</model>
      <man>Dodge</man>
    </soldCar>
  </carExo>
  <carExo id="CAR0005_01">
    <dealVen id="CAR0005_02">
      <name>John</name>
      <surname>Smith</surname>
    </dealVen>
    <soldCar>
      <amount>1811.10</amount>
      <lotNumber>3</lotNumber>
      <model>Dot</model>
      <man>Datsun</man>
    </soldCar>
  </carExo>
</CarStuff>
```

Comment: Helpful as it shows the other way round via XSLT (and early binding) +

Comment: Indeed. And even more XSLT is portable and not restricted to VBA. OP can use this same XSL script in other languages to transform original XML: Java, PHP, Python, even PowerShell and Bash! No `For` loops or `If...Then` logic needed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to remove all lines that contain `>NA<`.

This isn't really a programming question (so it's [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)) but here's a quick answer using [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to bring up the find replace dialog.
- In the `Find what:` text box include your regex: `.*>NA<.*\r?\n` *(where the `\r` is optional in case the file doesn't have Windows line endings)*.
- Leave the `Replace with:` text box empty.
- Make sure the `Regular Expression` radio button in the Search Mode area is selected.
- lick `Replace All` and voilà!  All lines containing `>NA<` have been removed.

[image: NPP repl line example]

<sub>(Answer adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876296/regex-remove-lines-containing)).</sub>

Comment: Wish it was this simple. The <man>Ford</man> may also have lines with NA, but these should be kept. That is the reason I'm looking for fields where <man> is NOT Ford or Dodge.

In addition only two lines above <man> should be checked for NA.

Comment: a one-time thing? or something that needs to be done repeatedly?

Comment: There are a number of ways to tackle this depending on a few things like whether the file is properly formatted XML (as opposed to your sample, missing top-level, etc), as well as where this file is coming from, whether this is a 1-time change, where the data is going when you're done, etc.

Comment: Two lines above <man> should be checked when it is not Ford or Dodge. 

E.g. - script checks line by line, find NOT Ford or Dodge on line 4, goes up one line to 3rd and if it is NA - removes line, else leaves as is. Then goes up another line to 2nd and checks if it is NA - same logic as line 3. Resumes from the line 4 where it found NOT Ford or Dodge, and does the same operation until the end of file.

Comment: Unfortunately unable to share the file, but it is a well formatted xml with the fields I described being in their nodes.

Comment: I can't think of an easily-explained way to do that especially without seeing some data.  I'm a bit of a data geek so I could likely write a quick sub to accomplish that but not without a test file... You could always make a sample one with fake data, and 10 records. (and the appropriate headers etc so its representative of the actual file).

Comment: ...now I'm curious!  Which lines could be "NA"?  Any of the 3 besides "<man>"?  Will there always be 4 _(and only 4)_ items per record (number/year/model/man) ?

Comment: I'll try to mock-up something. There's more data. but only one group requires amendments, it contains a fixed number of nodes of which <year> and <model> must be removed or kept based on <man> value.

Comment: always just those 4 items for this node?

Comment: Thanks, that's much more clear example; unfortunately I'm out of time for the moment....  in the meantime, have you tried Excel's built in XML tools?  (ie, xml table or source pane options when just Ctrl+O opening the xml file in Excel?)