# NotePad++ : How to delete a line ( also the next line) that contains a specific word?

Tags: notepad++

Let’s say for example we have this text and I want to delete every line that containts" delete me " and also the next line using NotePad++

```
a random text here1111
a random text here2222
a random text here delete me3333
a random text here 4444
delete me a random text here5555
a randomtext66666
```

So after applying what I want , the text is gonna be like this :

```
a random text here1111
a random text here2222
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex: Remove lines containing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876296/regex-remove-lines-containing)

Comment: @ArnoC this is not a duplicate , because in my case I want to delete two lines not only 1

Comment: To clarify, just make a regex so that it selects said line and the next one. Then the problem is reduced to the post linked above me.

Comment: Also agree with @ArnoC A duplicate is not exact the same question, it is the same subject which is explained in the provided link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `.*delete me.*\R.*(?:\R|$)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
.*delete me.*   : literally "delete me" surrounded with 0 or more any character but newline
\R              : any kind of line break
.*              : 0 or more any character but newline
(?:             : start non capture group
  \R            : any kind of line break
 |              : OR
   $            : end of line
)               : end group
```

**Result for given example:**

```
a random text here1111
a random text here2222
```

Comment: good answer , but how about the last 2 lines , it should be deleted too ??

Comment: if before the last  line contains delete me these  2 last lines won't be affected

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by making a regex matching your problem.

In your case such a regex would be:

```
(.)*(delete me)(.)*\n(.)*
```

This selects the line itself and the next one. Now it is only a matter of deleting the lines corresponding to said regex why is a possibility in notepad++. (see [Regex: Remove lines containing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876296/regex-remove-lines-containing))

If you want to tweak the regex feel free to toy around with it. [Regxr](https://regexr.com/) allows very easy tweaking and testing of any regular expression.

[image: Example on regxr.com]

Comment: hi , thank you for your answer , what about Notepad++ do u have any idea how can I do it ?

Comment: In my answer there is a link on how to do it in notepad ++.

Comment: Im sorry @ArnoC but in the link above I didn't find anything helpful , anyway , I've found the solution in the other answer , thanks again for your help